# How would I break up a sentence?

Tags: java

I have to write a program that separates the following:

> He said, "That's not a good idea."

Into:

> He
>
> said
>
> That
>
> s
>
> not
>
> a
>
> good
>
> idea

I've been asked to use Character.isLetter() and some sort of loop. Not sure how to proceed.

Comment: Use Character.isLetter() and some sort of loop?

Comment: Please visit the [help] and read [ask].  You are expected to make some effort to solve the problem yourself, and show your work.  SO is not a code-writing service.

Comment: @JSox You're welcome to call me nasty things, but you've literally been told how to do it, and state as such in your question. You've also shown us no indication you've tried anything to implement it. If you want to hand down a coding spec and have someone build it for you, hire someone.

Comment: I'm really sorry. I've been working on this code to no avail for quite a while now. Again, I'm really sorry for what I said.

Comment: @JSox if you've been working on it for a while, you must have *something* to show in the question.

Comment: @JSox Apology accepted. I'd suggest showing us the code you've put together.

Comment: `String word = "He said, 'That's not a good idea.'";
        
        for (int x = 0; x <= 34; x++)
        {
        word.split("\\s+");
        System.out.println(word);
        }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use a split function

```
for ( String s : string.split( "\\W+" ) )
        System.out.println( s );
```

or do something like

```
int start = 0;
    for ( int i = 0; i < string.length(); i++ ) {
        if ( !Character.isLetter( string.charAt( i ) ) || i == ( string.length() - 1 ) ) {
            int end = i;
            if ( i == ( string.length() - 1 ) && Character.isLetter( string.charAt( i ) ) )
                end = i + 1;
            String result = string.substring( start, end );
            start = i + 1;
            if ( result.isEmpty() || result.equals( " " ) )
                continue;
            System.out.println( result );
        }

    }
```

That should split up on non alphabets

Comment: "I've been asked to use Character.isLetter() and some sort of loop."

Comment: Sorry missed that part check it out now pretty sure it should do the trick

Comment: The first one doesn't use the required methods; the second one only happens to work because the string doesn't end with a letter.

Comment: ^ thanks for pointing that out fixed it to work otherwise

Answer (score 0):

loop through the string with an index and check if isLetter is false, then use this index to start a new element in your array.

Answer (score 0):

Like the other user said use the loop with references to the string indexes. If that index is not a character, such as a blank space, it should be the ending/starting of a word. You would use that new index range to your advantage.